# Symbol name in LT Spice

Tags: circuit-analysis, ltspice, electrical

Hi I'm trying to follow through on a lab assignment and I cant find one LT Spice symbol that the instructor is using to model a perfect transformer. The picture of the symbol is given in this post. I just need to know what name it has so i can look it up.
[image]

Comment: It looks like a voltage-controlled voltage source (VCVS).

Answer (score 0):

SPICE has a very strict relationship between the initial letter of a component's designator and the type of component. In LTSpice (and many other SPICEs), `E` indicates a voltage-controlled voltage source. From the LTSpice help file:

[image]